# s.replaceAll() not working Java/AndroidSDK

Tags: java, android, string, replace, replaceall

Hi there I'm trying to replace part of a (html) string but it's not working. And yes I am setting it to a new variable.

```
String newsBody = item.htcontent.replaceAll("resolveuid", "www.urlnotimportant.nl/resolveuid");
```

Why is isn't this working?

I think it has to do with the [img/] tags. Within those is the "resolveuid" string I'm trying to replace.

Comment: Isn't replaceAll() expecting a regex ?

Comment: "it's not working" isn't a good description of what's happening. Please give details of what you expect vs what's actually happening.

Comment: @bitbox: Yes it does, `resolveuid` is a valid regex, requiring an `r` followed by an `e` and so on.
@Jens Vossnak: What is the value of the `item.htcontent` and `newsBody` variables?

Comment: @npinti : of course it's valid. But that may explain why he's not getting the expected result.

Comment: So is what you are saying that `newsBody` does not have all "resolveuid" replaced? Or that the `item.htcontent` remains unchanged (which is to be expected).

Comment: @bitbox: You are correct on that, that is why I asked him for the value of the variables.

Comment: Hi thanks for the replies. @Jon Skeet By 'is not working' I mean it leaves the String unchanged. I expect the item.htcontent string, wich is the HTML body of a news post fetched from an rss feed, to be changed so that each occurrance of 'resolveuid/#UIDHERE#' is replaced by 'www.urlnotimportant.nl/resolveuid/#UIDHERE#' I know it should work as I am doing the same thing in an adobe Air app.

Comment: @npiti The value of newsBody is the complete HTML body of the post With a header and footer.

Comment: @predi No the newsBody remains unchanged.

Comment: You should post the contents of `item.htcontent`. If `newsBody.equals(item.htcontent)` is indeed returning `true` for you then the latter does not contain the string you wish to replace. You can test for this with a number of `java.lang.String` methods, such as check if `item.htcontent.indexOf("resolveuid")` is returning -1.

Answer (score 0):

The ReplaceAll() method takes a regex as first parameter. Perhaps your first parameter is not matching the way you expect it to.
See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String, java.lang.

Comment: The OP is most likely just trying to replace one string with another. Sice each string is also a regular expression which represents a set of acceptable strings of length 1, the fact that the method accepts regexes as the first argument is not really relevant, IMHO.

Comment: That said, `String.replace` is specifically intended for replacing literal strings, so the OP might as well use it here.

Answer (score 0):

This code is a correct implementation of prefixing the image links from this:

```
 <img src="resolveuid/832c2b08888aba0faccae78a14e9c764" alt="photo">
```

to this:

```
 <img src="www.urlnotimportant.nl/resolveuid/832c2b08888aba0faccae78a14e9c764" alt="photo">
```

except that of course, no code is shown in the question that would move the modified HTML back to place.

What you have to do is to assign the modified string back like this following the replacement:

```
item.htcontent = newsBody;
```

Comment: I know it should work as I am doing the same thing in an adobe Air app and the images always load.

Comment: @JensVossnack - It turns out that recent versions of Plone etc. can handle `resolveuid` replacements in the middle of the URL.  Updated answer based on that.